# how to delete photo from server using entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

i m uploading the photo using file upload control.

the code using to save photo

```
      FileUpload1.SaveAs((Server.MapPath("~/PicUpload/") + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

the code using to delete

```
 Pic DelImg = (from anything in DB.Pics
                  where anything.id == sid
                  select anything).FirstOrDefault();

    DB.Pics.DeleteObject(DelImg);
    DB.SaveChanges();
```

now if i want to delete that photo from photo folder by entity  how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/PicUpload/") + DelImg.FileName);`
Replace DelImg.FileName with whatever variable has the file name.

Entity framework has no knowledge that your database row has a column that refers to a file on the filesystem and is not going to modify anything but your database.